# How Can I Monitor The Database Transactions in my multi-threaded, EJB2 JBoss Application?

Tags: java, oracle, jboss, database-deadlocks

I have encountered a reproducible Oracle deadlock within my application. An initial investigation of the code has not thrown up any obvious cause, so I would like to re-create the situation while logging the SQL being run and most importantly, the transactions they are occurring within.

I started adding my own debug statements, but this seems like I am re-inventing the wheel and has already proved error prone (I initially missed that one of my EJB methods was defined as "RequiresNew")

Are there tools which will do this? I've looked at:

- log4jdbc, but it is not clear from the docs that I've seen that it
  will log the separate transactions, plus it doesn't support
  datasources, so I'd need work round that.
- jdbcslog - also not clear if it would log transactions

Or am I missing some more obvious way to do this?

Comment: What causes did you look for?

Comment: Two separate transactions, locking the same resource (rows) in a different order. i.e transaction 1 updates row a, transaction 2 updates row b, transaction 1 then tries to update row b but waits because transaction 2 already has it, transaction 2 tries to update row a and waits because transaction 1 already has it. Bingo - deadlock. I've looked for that scenario and then more complex ones spanning more resources.

Comment: What isolation level are you setting?  SERIALIZABLE?

Comment: Honestly, my way of handling this kind of thing is to log everything to a flat file and dig through it.  Old-fashioned, I know.  Its only saving grace is that it works.  Share and enjoy.

Comment: The database itself exposes lock information in various views. It is a bit involved for regular developers but an Oracle DBA should be able to get you the information. Specifically what was being waiting on, what was locked and by who.

Comment: @duffymo - it is READ COMMITTED which I believe is appropriate. Would this cause an issue?

Comment: @Brian - I'm aware of the trace files, but I thought that would only give me the last query from each of the deadlocked transactions (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9084429/finding-all-statements-involved-in-a-deadlock-from-an-oracle-trace-file) . Are there other views I can use, particularly if I can reproduce the issue (i.e set up the view in advance)?

Comment: @BobJarvis - thanks. I'd agree, if it wasn't for the transactions. I only need to miss one, and then my output is misleading, as I've already found out.

Comment: @Disco 3 - SERIALIZABLE is the most restrictive.  You should know the consequences of your choice and what's appropriate for your use case.

Comment: @duffymo - yes SERIALIZABLE was inappropriate for my situation

Answer (score 0):

Solved similar case a few times. It's very difficult (I call it lucky) to find solution in complicated app just from your session logging. (Oracle kills one of these sessions. One is killed and the other one lives on happily)

Best solution is to ask your DBA (or if you have access to your oracle instalation, you can google and then get them yourself, it's not sou complicated) for trace file(this file is mentioned in exception of killed session, so search your alert log), there will be deadlock graph. (just fulltext trace file for DEADLOCK)

Just look here for exact information how to look into your trace file. [LINK](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/deadlocks.php)